# AWS presigned url

Tags: amazon-web-services, pre-signed-url

I was wondering whether the AWSAccessKeyId in the presigned urls are static? Do these ever change (either over time) or are they unique linked to the user that generated it?

Comment: The key in the URL is whatever you used to sign the URL. Its useful lifetime is that of your underlying IAM user credentials (which you control) or the STS session credentials that you generated (which you control, up to an expiration limit) that you decided to use to sign the URL.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the credentials used to sign the URL.

If it begins with `AKIA`, then it's a long-lived user access key. These exist as long as the user chooses to let them exist, although it's a good practice to rotate your keys regularly.

If it begins with `ASIA`, then it's an assumed role key. These typically expire in an hour (although they can live longer).

*What's your **real** question?*

Comment: the urls are quite long... I was hoping to split the urls up and store the static stuff, e.g. host name, only once... then just have some json for the dynamic stuff

Comment: @ebg11 why? What is your goal here? What is the value in deconstructing the pre-signed URL?

Comment: so I can reduce storing common parts for multiple urls... Im trying to reduce bandwidth for lots of presigned urls.

Comment: There is no need to "store" pre-signed URLs. Rather, they should be generated _when they are needed_, with a short expiry (eg 5 minutes).